# QA on MS word Run-time Error 4248

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a VB script on MS word. The program is fine when I ran the program on my computer. But it is failed when the document is opened in protected mode.

Since the ms word will enter the protected view mode if the files are downloaded from the Internet and my word file is generated on the server side.

After  opening the word in protected mode and clicking the "Enable Editing" button , the word is existed from the "protected view mode" and change to "Compatibility Mode". And the ms word start to execute the VBA program.

Here is the program.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  If Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing Then
        createButtonFunction (ActiveDocument.Tables.Count)
    End If
End Sub
```

The program keep on saying that "ActiveDocument" is not found. But the number of activate document is 1.

How can I set the "ActiveDocument" properties back again after the word is change from "protected view mode" and change to "Compatibility Mode" ????

Comment: Problem Solved. The Document is null since the word is already open. But the event of document is still fired and causing this problem.Don;t use the default Document and  activate document when the document will be opened in protected view mode.

Comment: Dim doc As Word.Document

    Set doc = ThisDocument 

    createButtonFunction (doc.Tables.Count)

Use the ThisDocument is  as same as Activate document for my case.

Comment: It would be great if you could post this as an answer to your own question, with more details (the complete answer).